# Java Spark - split dataset based on boolean function

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to make data checks on a `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<Row>`. My current plan so far was :

First, iterate on each row :

```
accountingData.foreachPartition((Iterator<Row> rows) -> {
    while (rows.hasNext()) 
    { 
         Row row = rows.next();
    }
}
```

Second, iterate on each data check. They implement an interface

```
public interface SanityCheck {
    Boolean isValid(Row dataRow);
}
```

The third part of the plan was to dispatch the rows into a dataset that contains only rows that passed all checks, and one dataset that contains a copy of failing records per failing test, with additional column giving information about which check failed.

In total it would look something like

```
// private final SanityChecks[] sanityChecks;
 
StructType schema = originalDataset.schema();
  Dataset<Row> valids = spark.createDataFrame(Collections.emptyList(), schema);
  Dataset<Row> rejects = spark.createDataFrame(Collections.emptyList(), schema);

  originalDataset.foreachPartition((Iterator<Row> rows) -> {
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rows.next();
                Boolean isValidRow = true;
                for (SanityCheck check: sanityChecks) {
                    if (!check.isValid(row)))
                    {
                        isValidRow = false;
                        row.withColumn("failingCheck", lit(check.getClass().getName()))
                        rejects.union(row);
                    }
                
                }
                if(isValidRow) valids.union(row);
            }
        });
```

Now that doesn't compile, appending a row to a dataset apparently doesn't go work with union. Besides, withColumn isn't a method of the Row object (it's from the Dataset object).

Is this the correct approach ? How to add column to Row and append Row to Dataset ?

Edit : Sanity checks can be done at Dataset/frame level easily. They would be comparable to questions like "does the amount has a currency and is that currency a known one", "is it an actual valid date" or "is that value within this range". This can be done with where/join/filter/rexp etc...

If we change SanityCheck would then change to be something like (example of a nullity check)

```
 public ControlStatus checkStatus(Dataset<Row> data) {
        Column condition = col(fieldName).isNull().or(col(fieldName).equalTo(""));
        Dataset<Row> rejectedRows = data.where(condition);
        Dataset<Row> validRows    = data.where(not(condition));
        rejectedRows.withColumn("rejectReason", lit(rejectReason));
        return new ControlStatus(rejectedRows, validRows, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

But if I'm going in this direction I meet troubles with consolidating the various datasets produced by each SanityCheck : The consolidated reject list is easy, as it takes only one check failed to invalidate the entire record so the reject list is just the union of all checks' failures (as a record can fail multiple checks). Valid record on the other hands would appear in every single check valid list, and I have to remove the duplicate. That seemed to be a bad idea to me as it is a O(n²) operation that doesn't seem to be parrallelized nicely but maybe I overthink it ?

Comment: Iteration as you know it from programming world is a bad idea in the big-data world and should be used only when there is no alternative. This being said, the following question would be if you have investigate extensively implementing the SanityCheck logic using Spark Dataframe API? As for foreachPartition if allows you to go through elements of the partition fast, this doesn't mean you should use to create a new dataset within it i.e creating a new Dataframe

Comment: @abiratsis Initially I had plans for SanityCheck implementation to take Dataset<Row> argument and use Spark Dataset where / isNull / join etc... producing a Dataset of valids and rejects for each check. I changed my approach because that would have been nice for the rejects (just need to union all reject dataset for each control) but the total valid dataset was becoming the intersection of each control valid dataset and it seemed a bad idea. Am I wrong ?

Comment: It is possible to do the sanity checks on Dataframe/Dataset level? For instance using `df.where` and/or `df.filter` operators for checking the sanity rules. So what I mean is that you could check first if it is possible to do these checks on dataframe level and not row level

Comment: In order to check if these rules could be applied on Dataframe/Dataset level, maybe it would be easier to update your question with some of these rules.

Comment: @abiratsis I edited my question with my thoughts on passing entire `Dataset` to each `SanityCheck` and an implementation idea.

Comment: So it seems that you don't need to use Row level but Dataframe/Dataset level right? If you can use dataframes for these checks then you dont have to scale down to Row checks

Comment: @abiratsis Yes but then I have lots of duplicates when I aggregate the successful records for each sanity check. Doesn't it seems wasteful ? Isn't there another way ?

Comment: Well you can't get rid of duplicates with this code either. Here you are working in one particular partition, in order to get rid of duplicates you will need the entire dataset and therefore work with Dataframe/Dataset API

Comment: @abiratsis The idea in the code before the edit has no duplicates as was appending to the valid record dataset out of the sanity checks foreach loop. The reason why I didn't want to have to deal with those duplicates is because it felt like adding an O(n^2) operation that could be avoided, what do you think ?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by the previous to be honest, but I can ensure you that dropping duplicates is quite trivial operation achieved only through the Dataframe/Dataset API and as far as I know there isn't any other efficient approach. Also, it might be good to have in mind complexity when you write Spark code, but here you aren't just aiming that, you are trying to replace the default Spark behaviour without any obvious or significant reason.

Answer (score 0):

[Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/) solves this by embedding all the checks, via sql snippets, in a single column, the [ruleRunner](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/getting_started/flavours/#quality-qualitydata-rulerunner) would seem almost 100% of what you are asking for.  The sql snippet "sanity checks" have access to the entire row, views (on Spark 3.4, DBR 12.2) or even [custom lambda user functions](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/userFunctions/) to reduce duplication.

In the environment Quality was designed for the results of these DQ checks are saved with the data and allow filtering of passed / failed rows directly, allowing single pass processing which is important when dealing with thousands of rules and billions of rows.

Clearly this won't work with aggregates, but even they can be single pass [expressionRunner](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/expressionRunner/), but it seems you are more concerned about duplicate passed/failed rows than other aggregate checks.

You could do this yourself with a column per check and then a column to filter all checks but although this can increase complexity quickly it's definitely doable. Quality's approach was chosen based on performance, simplicity of user rule definition via sql and [low storage](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/model/storage/) costs and filtering performance.

If you choose to go down the route of a sanity check per column, do so through collecting the Column's first then adding them to the row, calling withColumn 100s of times is not always optimised out.

Comment: [evidence for why you shouldn't use withColumn in such a case](https://lansalo.wordpress.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/)